# Multiple, extendable components on Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Will keep it short: I have the need to build different components for my app. What I'm calling a "component" here is a collection of methods and constructors that repeats itself in many places of my app but is not necessarily exactly the same.

For the sake of an example, consider a pagination component. It is made of a few methods, a view and a template:

```
var Pagination = function() {
  this.View = Backbone.View.extend({});
  this.method = function() {};
  this.method2 = function() {};
};

// Create instance
var myComponent = new Pagination();
```

Heavily abstracted code, but gives the idea. Now, I've created a "Component" constructor to aid me in my task. It is fairly simple:

```
Component = function() {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};

_.extend(Component.prototype, {
    initialize: function() {}
});

Component.extend = Backbone.Model.extend;
```

This allows me to build multiple instances of the same component with slightly different methods or contents, without having to rebuild the same thing over and over again:

```
var Pagination = Component.extend({
  View: Backbone.View.extend({}),

  method: function() {},

  method2: function() {}
}};

// Create instance
var myComponent = new Pagination();
```

So far so good. `myComponent` has the list of methods as well as the constructor for the View. Here is where the problem lies: for some of my Components's instances I need to extend not only the component itself, but the Backbone constructors inside it as well. Say, for example, that I want to extend (not replace) the View inside my pagination component. That's were everything falls down.

This is the last approach I've had, but the basic idea is: I have components that repeat themselves frequently in my app but with slight differences between them. These components may include methods, backbone constructors and primitive values inside of them. I need to be able to extend these but ALSO be able to extend it's individual parts (Backbone constructors) if the need arises.Anyone has an idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: `myComponent.View = myComponent.View.extend({ ... })`? or pass options to `Pagination` constructor which could be used to extend `View`.

Comment: I thought of both options. The first one seems terribly verbose, since I need to create a new component and then extend the constructors within to finally build the instance inside it that I can finally use. It's also been kinda hard to figure out WHERE I should do all this in my code (the way I've structured it, that is). Second one would require me to build a custom extend function that would do various things, since the component could have multiple constructors (2 or more views, for example), it feels like it'll be quite a sluggish process.